# Flutter how to add id to firebase documentsnapshot

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting products from firebase firestore. Is it possible to add id to every product, from 0,1,2,3...?

Here is my code:

```
class ProductsRepository {

Firestore firestore = Firestore.instance;

Future<List<Product>> getProducts() async =>
  firestore.collection("products").getDocuments().then((result) {
    List<Product> _allProducts = [];
      for (DocumentSnapshot product in result.documents) {
        _allProducts.add(Product.fromSnapshot(product));
        }
        return _allProducts;
      });}
```

Comment: What are problem are you trying to solve by adding these IDs?  You might be doing something that will only cause you trouble later. Firestore does not really support assigning sequential numbers to documents (like SQL autoincrement IDs), unless you assign them all at the same time.  If you try to write more documents later, you will not easily be able to pick up where you left off.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Just adding an index to keep track of the snapshot data.

```dart
class ProductsRepository {
  Firestore firestore = Firestore.instance;

  Future<List<Product>> getProducts() async {
    firestore.collection("products").getDocuments().then(
      (result) {
        List<Product> _allProducts = [];
        int index = 0;
        for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot in result.documents) {
          Product product = Product.fromSnapshot(snapshot)..id = index;
          _allProducts.add(product);
          index += 1;
        }
        return _allProducts;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But with this code I get error: The argument type 'Product' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DocumentSnapshot'.

Comment: Fixed a variable name. Try now

Comment: I get warning: This function has a return type of 'FutureOr<List<Product>>', but doesn't end with a return statement.
Try adding a return statement, or changing the return type to 'void'.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to avoid creating a custom ID.
The better approach would be to use a code like that:

```
DocumentReference contactDB = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('products')
          .doc(_product.id);
```

In this case you can easily update later if the _product.id is not null, else _product.id is null, firebase will create a random ID for you.